# How do I create a link to the author's profile on the node that user created?

Tags: nodes, users, navigation, redirection

I want a create a link on each node page, which redirects to the profile page of the user who created that particular node.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please don't edit question in a way that renders existing answers invalid. It's called [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) and not liked. If you have another question, ask it as another question.

Comment: Once the question gets answers, its meaning cannot be changed, or the given answers would be invalidated. Furthermore, we like when questions show the OP tried to find the solution before asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom block with this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['author'] = array(
    'info' => t('author'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();

  switch($delta) {
    case 'author' :
      $block['title'] = NULL;

      ////////////////////////////////////////////
      $link = NULL;    
      if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) {
        $node = arg(1);
        if (!empty($node->uid)) {
          $link = l('view all work', 'user/' $node->uid);
        }    
      }
      //////////////////////////////////////////

      $block['content'] = $link;

      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

And set this block to nodes page with context, panels or native drupal blocks page.

Comment: i did'nt get you, but i tried this code it giving some error.Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 2

Comment: Edited to show how to include on a custom block

Comment: i have insert this code in template.php but its showing error in line ' $block['content'] = l('view all work', 'user/' $node->uid);'

Comment: This code is for a custom module, if you want only the script to use on template.php assigning it to a variable use only the snipet

Comment: not working..please suggest some other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default functionality available on Drupal. on detail pages author detail appears.

Just edit your content type display setting and check

> "Display author and date information. Author username and publish date
>   will be displayed."

See the screenshot [image: w3web the Drupal mentor www.w3web.in]

After that your can prepare link of author on theme preprocess or hook_node_view to make it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node--content-type.tpl.php node template file for showing the profile link of the user who created the node.
you can use $node->uid to find the user id and then use user_load() function to load the user OR profile2_load_by_user($account, $type_name = NULL) it will give you the profile url for the user if you are using the profile2 module and the you can create the link using the l() function.